# How find this sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(r(i)+\sigma{(i)}$

Tags: number-theory

> Give the postive integer number $n$,for any $i=1,2,\cdots,n$
>
> (1):Let $r({i})$ be the remainder of the division of $n$ by $i$,
>
> (2): $\sigma{(n)}$ is denote the sum of the (positive) divisors of $n$, including $1$ and $n$ itself
>
> define  $$a_{n}=r(1)+r(2)+\cdots+r(n)+\cdots\sigma{(1)}+\sigma{(2)}+\cdots+\sigma{(n)}$$
> Find the closed form $a_{n}$

It is clear

$$a_{1}=r(1)+\sigma{(1)}=0+1=1$$
$$a_{2}=r(1)+r(2)+\sigma{(1)}+\sigma{(2)}=0+0+1+3=4$$
$$a_{3}=r(1)+r(2)+r(3)+\sigma{(1)}+\sigma{(2)}+\sigma{(3)}=0+1+0+1+3+4=9$$
$$a_{4}=r(1)+\cdots+r(4)+\sigma{(1)}+\cdots+\sigma{(4)}=0+0+1+0+1+3+4+7=16$$

so I guess $$a_{n}=n^2$$

But I can't prove it

Comment: I think you mean the remainder of the division of $n$ by $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{i}\right\rfloor i+r(i) \implies r(i)=\left(n-\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{i}\right\rfloor i\right)$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(k)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nr(k)+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(k)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left(n-k\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{k}\right\rfloor \right)+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=n^2$

Comment: nice answer! oh i forget this indenity.+1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try induction on $n$.

It would be better to use the notation $r(i,n)$
rather than just $r(i)$, because it depends  on both $i$ and $n$.

Comment: hello,how to induction?